# How much weight of a whole life chicken is a supermarket whole chicken?

Tags: chicken, weights

If you buy a whole chicken in the supermarket it is defeathered, without head and feet and with the inner organs removed (sometimes you get some organs in a bag but I'm going to ignore that for this question). What I would like to know is how much, in terms of weight of a living chicken is a whole supermarket chicken? How much weight are the various pieces that are removed? If this makes a difference, assume the supermarket chicken weighs 1.5 kgs (a little over 3 pounds).

Comment: I think any answer is going to be extremely vague – is there a specific reason you're asking?

Comment: It's an interesting question to want to know the answer to, there needs be no other reason. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broiler chickens, at least in the US, are bred to grow quickly.  They are usually slaughtered when then weigh about 4 pounds, which is at about 7 to 9 weeks.  In general, a grocery store broiler weighs about 3 to 3.5 pounds.  As the comments above suggest, this is a very general response.  It would be difficult to be more accurate.